# Can't see gridview content when using fragments

Tags: android

This is important: using tabbed activity (deprecated) everything works fine with my code, this problem only comes when I use fragments.
I have three tabs, where each tab is a fragment. Layout is the same for every tab:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView android:id="@+id/newsView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Difference is for cursor loader's query.
Each fragment, indeed, implements LaderCallbacks:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(container == null)
        return null;

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_grid, container,false);
    dataSource = new MyCursorAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), null);
    GridView grid = (GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.newsView);
    grid.setAdapter(dataSource);
   getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);

    return v;
```

and for the rest of the code (cursor query for example) I'm 100% sure, as it worked before switching to fragments.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...it was just another programming error, nothing wrong with the code posted..sorry!